# TCPListener with multiple Clients

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I use layered architecture. I create a server. I want the server to listen when the data arrives.
This is my server code in the DataAccess layer.

```
public class ServerDal : IServerDal
{
    private TcpListener server;
    private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    public bool ServerStart(NetStatus netStatus)
    {
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(netStatus.IPAddress), netStatus.Port);
            server.Start();
            status = true;
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Server Error..." + ex);
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }

    public string ReceiveAndSend(NetStatus netStatus)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        String data = null;

        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "TcpIpReceive");
        mutex.WaitOne();

        if (!client.Connected)
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;
            if ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Error..." + ex);
            client.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I can listen to the client that first connects to the server. When the first connecting client disconnects, I can listen to the second connecting client.
I want to listen when both clients send data. How can I do that ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a code snippet for HTTP via `TcpClient` but on [Russian StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567). Unlimited clients are supported at once. In short - use [Acynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). `TcpListener` exposes `async` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

```
    static List<TcpClient> tcpClients = new List<TcpClient>();
    public void ReceiveMessage(NetStatus netStatus)
    {
        try {
            TcpClient tcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            tcpClients.Add(tcpClient);

            Thread thread = new Thread(unused => ClientListener(tcpClient, netStatus));
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("[ERROR...] Server Receive Error = {0} ", ex.Message);
        }

    }
    public void ClientListener(object obj, NetStatus netStatus)
    {
        try 
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)obj;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

            while(true)
            {
                string message = null;
                message = reader.ReadLine();
                if(message!=null)
                {
                    netStatus.IncommingMessage = message;
                    Console.WriteLine("[INFO....] Received Data = {0}", message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[ERROR....] ClientListener Error = {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```